# Decoding serial packets, please check my work!

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have a Innovate LC-2 wideband and Megasquirt ECU. The Innovate wideband has RS232 serial output I would like to use instead of the default 0-5V analog output.

So I designed and built a board using a MAX3232, MCP2515/MCP2561 CANbus, and ATMEGA328PB. I also have a MAX31856 for EGT, LIS3DH for accel, and BMP280 for barometer. I also mucked about on forums and threads until I understood enough to decode the format. What I have now works, but I would like someone more experienced to check it for errors!

The serial format is described here...
https://www.innovatemotorsports.com/support/downloads/Seriallog-2.pdf

My code looks a bit like this, it is part of a main loop reading data from other sensors as data is ready, so the loop is non-blocking. The main loop also transmits data over canbus at set intervals.

This does work, but is there anything I can do to make it more resilient?

Thank you in advance!

```
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      EGO_rx_byte=Serial.read();                                            // pull data from serial
      if ( (EGO_rx_byte & 0xA2) == 0xA2 ) {                                 // synchronization byte - bits 15-8 1x1xxx1x 
         EGO_packet[0] = EGO_rx_byte;                                       // Store buffer data to Packet
         EGO_packet_index = 0 ;                                             // This is the start of the header packet, bits 15-8      
      }
      else if ((EGO_packet_index == 0) && ((EGO_rx_byte & 0x80) == 0x80)) { // If index = 0 & bit 7 = 1 = 2nd syncro byte
         EGO_packet_index=1;                                                // this is second half of header packet, bits 7-0
         EGO_packet[1]=EGO_rx_byte;                                         // store buffer data to packet
      }
      else if ((EGO_packet_index == 1) && ((EGO_rx_byte & 0x42) == 0x42)) { // If index = 1 & 0x42 is set on next packet likely valid LC2 packet...
         EGO_packet_index=2;                                                // This was the third packet in six - Zero indexed               
         EGO_packet[2]=EGO_rx_byte;                                         // Store buffer data to packet
      }
      else {
        EGO_packet_index++;                                                 // all else are data packets, increment the packet counter by one
        EGO_packet[EGO_packet_index]=EGO_rx_byte;                           // Store buffer data to packet in series
      }
      if (EGO_packet_index == 5) {                                          // Done recieving packets, ready to construct data... 2 words per EGO, 1 header packet        
         EGO_status = (EGO_packet[2] & B00011100) >> 2;                     // status bits are in word 1 bits 12-10                
         EGO_data = (EGO_packet[2] & B00000001) << 7;                       // AFR Multiplier - think this is programmed with lmprogrammer - bits 8, 6-0
         EGO_data += EGO_packet[3] & B01111111;                             // these are the 6-0 bits         
         EGO_lambda = EGO_packet[4] & B00111111;                            // 13 bit lambda value, data depends on status bits
         EGO_lambda = EGO_lambda << 7;                                      // shift bits from first half of data packet
         EGO_lambda += (EGO_packet[5] & B01111111);                         // add bits from second half of packet       
         switch (EGO_status) {                                              // Output data depends on Status
         case 0: Lambda = EGO_lambda; EGO_conn = 13;                        // EGO Output is valid - Lambda in 10 bit scale
         if (Lambda > 1023){Lambda = 1023;}break;                           // Megasquirt expects 0-1023 input value                       
         case 1:Lambda = 1023;EGO_conn = 13;break;                          // EGO Output is valid - reporting O2% in 1/10%
         case 2:EGO_conn = 10;Lambda =  500;break;                          // Free air calibration 
         case 3:EGO_conn = 11;Lambda =  500;break;                          // Need Calibration
         case 4:EGO_conn = 12;Lambda =  500;break;                          // Warmup
         case 5:EGO_conn = 10;Lambda =  500;break;                          // Heater Calibration
         case 6:EGO_conn = EGO_lambda;Lambda =  500;break;                  // Error code 1-9    
         case 7:EGO_conn = 0;Lambda =  500;break;                           // Reserved 
         default:Lambda =  507;EGO_conn = 0;break;                          // Something else is happening, output 14.7 and error 
         }                                                                            
    } 
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty robust to me as it is. You might like to make use if the `length` attribute of the header though to receive the right number of bytes for the payload though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Oh, you mean pulling the header length from the first packet to determine the number of following packets? I have some very poorly written code that does so, but I lack the hardware to test more than one LC-2 on the serial bus at the time!